# Issues creating a regex to extract code from Markdown

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract code from a string of Markdown and I'm very close. My code is:

````
import re

string = """
Lorem ipsum
```python
print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')
```
Lorem ipsum
"""

pattern = r'```(?:\w+\n)?(.*?)(?!.*```)'
result = re.search(pattern, string, re.DOTALL).group(1)
print(result)
````

And the result of this is:

````
print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')
`
````

You'll notice the only problem I have is the extra backtick at the end of that code block. I can't figure out what's matching that or how to remove it but I'm certain it has something to do with the negative lookahead I'm using.

Comment: Why not use a parser?

Comment: Can there be more than one code block in your text?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm doing something for fun where I'm trying to write the smallest piece of code that is capable of updating itself with ChatGPT  trying to keep imports to a minimum. No business use case but very entertaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first character which doesn't match ```` .*``` ```` (and hence terminates the match) is the `` ` `` at the start of the line after ```` print('foo```bar```foo') ````. See for example [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/UMHjzn/1). You'll note that this method doesn't work at all when there is more than one code block.

Probably the safest approach is to rely on the ```` ``` ```` being the first thing on the line. Then you can match up to the next occurrence of ```` ``` ```` at the start of a line instead:

````
^```(?:\w+)?\s*\n(.*?)(?=^```)```
````

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8iN6FJ/1)

In python:

````py
import re

string = """
Lorem ipsum
```python
print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')
```
Lorem ipsum
```python
print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')
```
Lorem ipsum
```
print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')
```
"""

pattern = r'^```(?:\w+)?\s*\n(.*?)(?=^```)```'
result = re.findall(pattern, string, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
print(*[r for r in result], sep='\n')
````

Output:

````
print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')

print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')

print('foo```bar```foo')
print('foo```bar```foo')
````

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you for the suggestion of checking that ``` was at the start of the line totally slipped my mind that I should do this.

Comment: @SeanBannister sometimes it just takes another set of eyes looking at the problem. I'm glad I could help.